# I don't understand while loops

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I am new to Java and I don't really understand while loops. I want to say 'if you don't want to choose the Warrior class then go back to the character select box.

```
while (chooseCharacter = true){

        String[] Character= {"Kitty", "Archer","Tank","Battlemage","Warrior"};
        int characterSelect = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog (null, "Choose your class", "Class Selection", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, Character, "Warrior");

        if(characterSelect == 4){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Warrior" + "\n" + "Attack 1: Slash" + "\n" + "10 Damage :: 98% Accuracy" + "\n" + "Attack 2: Spin Attack" + "\n" +  "25 Damage :: 67% Accuracy");
            String[] warriorChar= {"No", "Yes"};
            int warrior = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Would you like to choose Warrior as your class?", "Choose this class?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, warriorChar, "No");
            if(warrior == 0){
                chooseCharacter = true;
            }
            if(warrior == 1){
                chooseCharacter = false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

```
while(chooseCharacter = true)
                      ↑
```

You're assigning, not comparing. You should write:

```
while(chooseCharacter)
```

In Java, the expression of the assignment returns the *assigned* value, so your loop is equivalent to `while(true)`.

Note that it's very recommended to write

```
while(someBoolean)
```

instead of

```
while(someBoolean == true/false)
```

it can protect you from mistakes like the one you did, and also think about it in logical way, if you write `if(something == true)` it's like asking "if the value is true.. is true".

Answer (score 2):

use

```
while (chooseCharacter == true){
}
```

or

```
while (chooseCharacter){

}
```

**== is a operator for comparison and = is for assignment**